# Exchange Task collection for a value collection

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

Looking for a way to get values from task collection.
For exmaple i have

```
 List<Task<string>> strings
```

and i am looking for way to exchange it to

```
List<string> results
```

The only acceptable way i have found is to run foreach loop and use "await" or "result" on each task element, but i wonder is there any way to do it more simple like Task.WaitAll() but with result collection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`WhenAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=netcore-3.1)

> Creates a task that will complete when all of the Task objects in an
> enumerable collection have completed.

```
List<Task<string>> tasks = ...

var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Or if for some reason you are stuck in the 2008's, you could use [`Task.WaitAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitall?view=netcore-3.1#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_WaitAll_System_Threading_Tasks_Task___) and project the results to a list

> Waits for all of the provided Task objects to complete execution.

Comment: 2008 called, and said that it has not seen a `Task.WaitAll` or anything like that. The [.NET Framework 4.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework_version_history#.NET_Framework_4.0) was released on April 2010. 